# Am trying to get data across multiple struts

Tags: solidity

Am new to coding and solidity. trying to build a simple contract with the use case register one company, register two employees. Get all employees for registered company. Have the following code but am getting only the first employee that I registered

```
 // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.7.5;
contract Employee {
    
    uint256 companyIndex;
    uint256 employeeIndex;

   
    struct Company {
        string name;
        }

    struct Employee {
        uint256 companyId;
        string name;
        }    
    
    mapping(uint256 => Company) Companies;
    mapping(uint256 => Employee) Employees;

    ///***************************************Company*******************************************///

    function addCompany(string memory name) public
    {
        uint256 companyId = companyIndex++;
        Companies[companyId] = Company(name);
    }


    function getCompany(uint256 companyId) public view returns (uint256, string memory)
    {
        return (companyId, Companies[companyId].name);
    }
 
 ///***************************************Employee*******************************************///

    function addEmployee(uint256 companyId,string memory name) public

    {
        uint256 employeeId = employeeIndex++;
        Employees[employeeId] = Employee(companyId,name);//get error undeclared identifier 
    }


    function getEmployee(uint256 companyId) public view returns (uint256, string memory)
    {
        return (companyId, Employees[companyId].name);
    }

}
```

I registered the company (company 1). I registered employees (employee1, employee2). Now when I try to get employees for company1, I get only employee1. How can I get both employee1 and employee2.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting some state variables as `public` helps to debug. It is working alright for me.

How are you trying to get the first employee? With a 1? And the second employ with a 2? You are doing `companyIndex++` which will set the first company id to 0. And `employeeIndex++` will set the first employee id to 0. So, when you are trying to get the first employee you need to call `getEmployee(0)`, and the second `getEmployee(1)`.
If you don't want the ids to start at 0, then put the `++` to the left: `++companyIndex` and `++employeeIndex`.

I added some comments in your code:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.7.5;
contract Employee {
    
    uint256 public companyIndex;
    uint256 public employeeIndex;

   
    struct Company {
        string name;
        }

    struct Employee {
        uint256 companyId;
        string name;
        }    
    
    mapping(uint256 => Company) public Companies;
    mapping(uint256 => Employee) public Employees;

    ///***************************************Company*******************************************///

    function addCompany(string memory name) public
    {
        uint256 companyId = companyIndex++; // First company id will be 0
        // If you want the first company id to be 1, then consider adding the ++ at the beginning of companyIndex
        // uint256 companyId = ++companyIndex;
        Companies[companyId] = Company(name);
    }


    function getCompany(uint256 companyId) public view returns (uint256, string memory)
    {
        return (companyId, Companies[companyId].name);
    }
 
 ///***************************************Employee*******************************************///

    function addEmployee(uint256 companyId,string memory name) public

    {
        uint256 employeeId = employeeIndex++; // First employee id will be 0, second will be 1
        // If you want the first employee id to be 1, then consider adding the ++ at the beginning of employeeIndex
        // uint256 employeeId = ++employeeIndex; // Now, first employee id will be 1, second will be 2
        Employees[employeeId] = Employee(companyId,name);//get error undeclared identifier 
    }


    function getEmployee(uint256 companyId) public view returns (uint256, string memory)
    {
        return (companyId, Employees[companyId].name);
    }

}
```

How it looks in remix.ethereum.org:

[image]

A way to get all the employees of a company at once (also, need to use `pragma abicoder v2;`):

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.7.5;
pragma abicoder v2;

contract Employee {
    
    uint256 public companyIndex;
    uint256 public employeeIndex;

   
    struct Company {
        string name;
        }

    struct Employee {
        uint256 companyId;
        string name;
    }    
    
    mapping(uint256 => Company) public Companies;
    mapping(uint256 => Employee) public Employees;

    mapping(uint256 => Employee[]) public companyEmployees;

    ///***************************************Company*******************************************///

    function addCompany(string memory name) public
    {
        uint256 companyId = ++companyIndex; // First company id will be 0
        // If you want the first company id to be 1, then consider adding the ++ at the beginning of companyIndex
        // uint256 companyId = ++companyIndex;
        Companies[companyId] = Company(name);
    }


    function getCompany(uint256 companyId) public view returns (uint256, string memory)
    {
        return (companyId, Companies[companyId].name);
    }
 
 ///***************************************Employee*******************************************///

    function addEmployee(uint256 companyId,string memory name) public

    {
        uint256 employeeId = ++employeeIndex; // First employee id will be 0, second will be 1
        // If you want the first employee id to be 1, then consider adding the ++ at the beginning of employeeIndex
        // uint256 employeeId = ++employeeIndex; // Now, first employee id will be 1, second will be 2

        Employee memory emp = Employee(companyId,name);
        Employees[employeeId] = Employee(companyId,name);//get error undeclared identifier 

        // Add the employee to the companyEmployees array in this mapping
        companyEmployees[companyId].push(emp);
    }


    function getEmployee(uint256 companyId) public view returns (uint256, string memory)
    {
        return (companyId, Employees[companyId].name);
    }

    function getCompanyEmployees(uint256 companyId) public view returns(Employee[] memory) {

        return companyEmployees[companyId];

    }

}
```

Basically create another mapping to hold the employees for a company:

```js
mapping(uint256 => Employee[]) public companyEmployees;
```

Then in the `addEmployee` function add the employee to this mapping:

```js
//...
companyEmployees[companyId].push(emp);
```

Then create a new function to return it:

```js
    function getCompanyEmployees(uint256 companyId) public view returns(Employee[] memory) {

        return companyEmployees[companyId];

    }
```

Now, if you want to make your code a bit more readable and type-safe, you can upgrade the Solidity version and use custom `type`s for emplyeeId and companyId:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.16;
pragma abicoder v2;

type EmployeeId is uint;
type CompanyId is uint;
    
contract CompanyEmployee {

    uint256 public companyIndex;
    uint256 public employeeIndex;

    struct Company {
        string name;
        }

    struct Employee {
        CompanyId companyId;
        string name;
    }    
    
    mapping(CompanyId => Company) public Companies;
    mapping(EmployeeId => Employee) public Employees;

    mapping(CompanyId => Employee[]) public companyEmployees;

    ///***************************************Company*******************************************///

    function addCompany(string memory name) public
    {
        CompanyId companyId = CompanyId.wrap(++companyIndex); // First company id will be 0
        // If you want the first company id to be 1, then consider adding the ++ at the beginning of companyIndex
        // uint256 companyId = ++companyIndex;
        Companies[companyId] = Company(name);
    }


    function getCompany(CompanyId companyId) public view returns (CompanyId, string memory)
    {
        return (companyId, Companies[companyId].name);
    }
 
 ///***************************************Employee*******************************************///

    function addEmployee(CompanyId companyId, string memory name) public

    {
        EmployeeId employeeId = EmployeeId.wrap(++employeeIndex); // First employee id will be 0, second will be 1
        // If you want the first employee id to be 1, then consider adding the ++ at the beginning of employeeIndex
        // uint256 employeeId = ++employeeIndex; // Now, first employee id will be 1, second will be 2

        Employee memory emp = Employee(companyId,name);
        Employees[employeeId] = Employee(companyId,name);//get error undeclared identifier 

        // Add the employee to the companyEmployees array in this mapping
        companyEmployees[companyId].push(emp);
    }


    function getEmployee(EmployeeId employeeId) public view returns (Employee memory)
    {
        return Employees[employeeId];
    }

    function getCompanyEmployees(CompanyId companyId) public view returns(Employee[] memory) {
        return companyEmployees[companyId];
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. when you execute getCompany with 0 id, you get only one employee "John" but not "Doe". Is there a way for that function to return both "John" and "Doe"?

Comment: Pretty much like an SQL select * from employee where companyid=0, which would return employeeid 0 & 1

Comment: Aahhhhh, now I understand your concern. You can create a `mapping(uint256 => Employee[]) public companyEmployees;` mapping of an array of employees for a given company and add an employee when you creat it like: `companyEmployees[companyId].push(emp);` and return it in a `getCompanyEmployees(uint256 companyId) public view returns(Employee[] memory)` function. I updated the description so you see that example.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, yes that worked.